# Scroll window horizontal to element in devices and desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with a horizontal scroll since the page is wider that the viewport.
I also have a fixed menu and when the user clicks on a link in the menu the window should scroll to a particular element like code below.

This works fine in desktop but in devices the left value isn't the same so it will not scroll to the desired position. How can I calculate  the right left value so it works in all devices?

```
$('.link').bind('click', function () {
 window.scrollTo({
    top: null,
    left: 2600,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the value to scroll to dynamically by getting the `offset().left` of the target element.

Also note that `bind()` was deprecated a *long* time ago and you should not be using it. Use either `click()` or `on()` instead. I would also suggest checking the version of jQuery you're using. If it's older than 1.12.1 you should definitely upgrade it.

Here's an example of all the above:

```
$('.link').on('click', function () {
  window.scrollTo({
    left: $('#yourTargetElement').offset().left,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

Comment: That gives me a different value every time I click depending on what scrollposition I have on that time.

Comment: Ok - it depends on how your HTML and CSS is structured. Try using `position().left` instead

Comment: That will give me a value of 0 :/

Comment: In which case please add your HTML and CSS to the question. It's hard to debug something you haven't shown us

Comment: Thank you for your reply Rory, managed to solve it by some calculations of checking maximun scrolleft of page and scrollLeftvalue by $('body, html').scrollLeft() when element was in the middle of the screen in desktop. This gave me a value I then could use.